# clicking a link using selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I'm trying to download a file from this website (https://www.tusubtitulo.com/season/26/10) using a python script with selenium

Here it is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

site="https://www.tusubtitulo.com/season/26/10"
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
el = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Descargar").click()
driver.close()
```

But I'm receiving this error:

```
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

NoSuchElementException: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with link text 'Descargar'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"97","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:53425","User-Agent":"Python http auth"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"link text\", \"value\": \"Descargar\", \"sessionId\": \"be219f20-26b5-11e7-bfb9-63e6de8a8a0a\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/be219f20-26b5-11e7-bfb9-63e6de8a8a0a/element"}}
```

Link to see the xpath: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkYzG.jpg
I also have tried using the xpath, as explained in several answers, with the same result:

```
from selenium import webdriver

site="https://www.tusubtitulo.com/season/26/10"
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
xpath=".//*[@id='episodes']/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td[7]/a"
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
driver.close()
```

with the same result.

But if I use the "WebDriverWait" approach, I'm getting a different error:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

site="https://www.tusubtitulo.com/season/382/7"
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
xpath = ".//*[@id='episodes']/table[3]/tbody/tr[3]/td[7]/a"
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath))).click()
driver.close()
```

Error:

```
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

TimeoutException
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the admin of the website you are refering to. Our system doesn't allow request from script. You need to download from your browser. It's our rule.

Comment: Not the answer I was expecting! Can I ask you why is that your rule?

Comment: this is not a valid answer